# Calculating working days in python using BDays

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date

I started playing around with dates in python and came across a simple yet interesting scenario.

I intended to identify date n Business Days prior to a given date. Below is my code to achieve the same.
it works fine with weekends in the picture, but when it comes to public holidays, it doesn't take that as a holiday.

```
import datetime
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay

def getCalculatedDate(d):
    print(d)
    subtracted_value = d - BDay(5)
    print(subtracted_value)
    return subtracted_value

d = datetime.date(2020, 10, 8)
sub_val = getCalculatedDate(d)
print(d)
print(sub_val)
```

Please help me understand why is that so and is there any other way to achieve the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas CustomBusinessDay and USFederalHolidayCalendar as follows:

```
import datetime
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay

def getCalculatedDate(d, offset_days):
    us_bd = CustomBusinessDay(n=offset_days, calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())
    subtracted_value = d - us_bd
    return subtracted_value

d = datetime.date(2020, 12, 28)
print(d)
print(getCalculatedDate(d,5))
```